# Unable to upload a file into the firebase storage with an error: "Be careful, this may be a production service"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I followed the instructions and I created the ServiceAccountKey.json but when I try to upload a file to the Firebase Storage, I get an exception: "Be careful, this may be a production service".

[image]

Node.js 16

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.24.0
  firebase_database: ^9.1.6
  video_player: ^2.4.7
  camera: ^0.10.0+3
  cloud_firestore: ^3.5.1
  firebase_auth: ^3.11.2
  dio: ^4.0.6
  flutter_cors: ^1.3.2
  convert: ^3.0.2
  flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  firebase_storage: ^10.3.11
```

The code:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
    
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
    
admin.initializeApp({
           credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
           databaseURL: "https://123-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com"
});
    
    
exports.saveVideoOnStorage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    inputFile = '/Users/nativvered/pubspec.yaml';
    const myStorage = admin.storage();
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('gs://123.appspot.com/Files');

    await bucket.upload(inputFile);
});
```

The exception:

```
Google API requested!
   - URL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
   - Be careful, this may be a production service.
⚠  Google API requested!
   - URL: "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/challenge-me-vn.appspot.com/Videos/o?uploadType=multipart&name=pubspec.yaml"
   - Be careful, this may be a production service.
⚠  functions: Error: Not Found
    at new ApiError (/Users/nativvered/Documents/MyFlluter/vered2/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/nodejs-common/util.js:78:15)
    at Util.parseHttpRespMessage (/Users/nativvered/Documents/MyFlluter/vered2/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/nodejs-common/util.js:180:41)
    at Util.handleResp (/Users/nativvered/Documents/MyFlluter/vered2/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/nodejs-common/util.js:154:76)
    at /Users/nativvered/Documents/MyFlluter/vered2/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/nodejs-common/util.js:500:22
    at onResponse (/Users/nativvered/Documents/MyFlluter/vered2/functions/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:228:7)
    at /Users/nativvered/Documents/MyFlluter/vered2/functions/node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:157:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

Answer (score 1):

"Be careful, this may be a production service." is not an error, but a warning that your local emulator is not talking to an emulated storage API.

The actual error is "Error: Not Found" which is because the file you want to upload cannot be found or is not accessible. In your case, you cannot upload the file at `/Users/nativvered/pubspec.yaml` because it is located outside of your functions directory.

You have two options:

- You need to send the file you want to upload in the body of the request you are making to your `saveVideoOnStorage` function in the code that is calling the function. (recommended)
- You copy the `pubspec.yaml` into your `functions` directory before starting up the emulator and then upload it from there. (not recommended, but useful for testing)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the bucket is gs://123.appspot.com/ and not gs://123.appspot.com/Files